# Work done by friction wrong in general physics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, friction

Though some general physics textbooks say that work done by friction isn't straightforward, many textbooks still calculate it as if it were a work done by a usual force, even without declaring that heat generation is ignored. Why is that?

Comment: What do you mean by “normal force”? A usual force? A force normal (perpendicular) to a surface?

Comment: Why do you think the heat generation means that you calculate the work done by the force differently?

Comment: What do you mean by "heat energy is ignored"?

Comment: @AaronStevens work done by friction isn't simply friction*displacement

Comment: @JMac heat generation/temperature rise ignored

Comment: @BobD usual force

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well basically say you have a total energy E and you move along a path with friction and then you will have friction loses $E_{loss}$. Now the remaining energy is $E_{eff}$

I.e $$E_{eff}= E-E_{loss}$$

We can get an expression for $E_{loss}$ by integrating the frictional force over the path. This is an easy integral if we assume friction to be cocnstant over the path.

I.e $$ \int f_{s} * dl =f_{s} *l$$, hence the energy losses is the frictional force * times the length which the body traveled

Comment: Maybe those textbooks call heat generation+work done by friction as friction*displacement?

Comment: Basically the energy loss term is the heat generation ( tho it could be in other stuff too like creating sounD)

Comment: May I understand your answer this way? Because there must be a force F counteracting friction and assume that force F is conservative/non-dissipative, then that force does work=F*x. Then no matter what energy loss contributes to: heat, sound etc, the loss must be F*x.

Comment: Well see we can't quite do that , we integrated the friction force along the path. Let's take a discrete example.

You start with an energy 10 E 

A frictional force acts on your motion and for each step you make you lose 1E unit of energy. 

Say you take three steps the right then one step left. You are ultimately at two steps to the right. But the energy loss is 4E

But say you just move two units to the right, then your energy loss is just 2E.

The loss is not always F*x. It is F times the DISTANCE .. note here that I said distance not displacement that you have travelled

Comment: May I say that, what is called 'work done by friction in general physics', is really 'mechanical energy loss due to friction', which is the exact work done by friction+heat generation/sound etc

Comment: yes that sounds right